# Passing files to a Nextflow process based on a group ID

Tags: groovy, nextflow

I am struggling with an issue that, probably, has a very basic solution.
In my (dsl2) nextflow workflow, I have a number of processes that output a tuple of a file and a value, which indicates the group of the input element.
Then, I have a last process that, for each group, collects all the files generated and works on them.
For example:

```
workflow {
generatePDF(input_channel)
generateCSV(input_channel)
generateTXT(input_channel)
mergeprocess( /*grouped input files from previous 3 processes */ ) 
}
```

And, as I mentioned the output for each generate* process is

```
tuple file(output_${samplename}.${extension}) val(${group})
```

For example, if I have the samples 1, 2 and 3 belonging to group A, 4 to group B and 5 and 6 to group C, I would like to pass as an input for the last process

*output_sample1.pdf output_sample2.pdf output_sample3.pdf output_sample1.csv output_sample2.csv output_sample3.csv output_sample1.txt output_sample2.txt output_sample3.txt*

*output_sample4.pdf output_sample4.csv output_sample4.txt*

*output_sample5.pdf output_sample6.pdf output_sample5.csv output_sample6.csv output_sample5.txt output_sample6.txt*

I have tested a combination of collect(), groupTuple and even join(), but nothing gave me the channel I need.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution, which is perhaps the 'basic' solution you may have been working towards, is to [mix](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#mix) your process outputs and then call the [groupTuple](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#grouptuple) operator, specifying the index of the element to be used as the grouping key using the `by` parameter:

```
generatePDF.out
    | mix( generateCSV.out, generateTXT.out )
    | groupTuple( by: 1 )
    | view()
```

However, this solution will 'wait' for all generate processes (generatePDF, generateCSV, generateTXT) to be completed before proceeding to merge *any* of the grouped outputs. This is because [groupTuple](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#grouptuple) ideally needs to know the number of items the grouped lists should contain:

> You should always specify the number of expected elements in each
> tuple using the `size` attribute to allow the `groupTuple` operator to
> stream the collected values as soon as possible.

If your generate processes all determine the same group for a given sample (which they probably do), you should be able to decouple this logic in such a way that allows you to predetermine the size of each group. You could then create a special grouping key (i.e. using [groupKey](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/v21.10.6/modules/nextflow/src/main/groovy/nextflow/extension/GroupKey.groovy) function) and use that to group the process outputs. The following example simply predetermines the group from parent directory, but hopefully should be applicable to your use case:

First, lets create some test data:

```
mkdir -p input_files/{A,B,C}
touch input_files/A/sample{1,2,3}.ext
touch input_files/B/sample4.ext
touch input_files/C/sample{5,6}.ext
```

Then, put the following in a file called `script.nf`:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2
```

```
process generatePDF {
    input:
    tuple val(sample_name), path(input_file)

    output:
    tuple val(sample_name), path("output_${sample_name}.pdf")

    """
    touch "output_${sample_name}.pdf"
    """
}
process generateCSV {
    input:
    tuple val(sample_name), path(input_file)

    output:
    tuple val(sample_name), path("output_${sample_name}.csv")

    """
    touch "output_${sample_name}.csv"
    """
}
process generateTXT {
    input:
    tuple val(sample_name), path(input_file)

    output:
    tuple val(sample_name), path("output_${sample_name}.txt")

    """
    touch "output_${sample_name}.txt"
    """
}
```

```
process merge_process {

    tag { group }

    echo true

    input:
    tuple val(group), path(input_files)

    """
    echo "group: ${group}"
    ls ${input_files}
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    Channel.fromPath( './input_files/*/*.ext' )
        | map { infile -> tuple( infile.parent.name, infile ) }
        | groupTuple()
        | map { group, files -> tuple( groupKey(group, files.size()), files) }
        | transpose()
        | set { input_ch }

    input_ch
        | map { key, infile -> tuple( infile.baseName, infile ) }
        | ( generatePDF & generateCSV & generateTXT )
        | mix
        | groupTuple( size: 3 )
        | set { outputs_ch }

    input_ch
        | map { key, infile -> tuple( infile.baseName, key ) }
        | join( outputs_ch )
        | map { sample, key, files -> tuple( key, files ) }
        | groupTuple()
        | map { key, grp_files -> tuple( key.toString(), grp_files.flatten() ) }
        | merge_process

}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run script.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.10.0
Launching `script.nf` [irreverent_lavoisier] - revision: aba248d32e
executor >  local (21)
[5d/5cd70d] process > generatePDF (1)   [100%] 6 of 6 ✔
[4c/c58256] process > generateCSV (2)   [100%] 6 of 6 ✔
[d2/93402c] process > generateTXT (5)   [100%] 6 of 6 ✔
[9b/04ea07] process > merge_process (C) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
group: B
output_sample4.csv
output_sample4.pdf
output_sample4.txt

group: A
output_sample1.csv
output_sample1.pdf
output_sample1.txt
output_sample2.csv
output_sample2.pdf
output_sample2.txt
output_sample3.csv
output_sample3.pdf
output_sample3.txt

group: C
output_sample5.csv
output_sample5.pdf
output_sample5.txt
output_sample6.csv
output_sample6.pdf
output_sample6.txt
```

Comment: I really don't mind waiting for all the processes to be completed before running the last one, so the first solution seems the most straightforward. But I definitely wanna test around the second too, even though in my case I cannot take advantage of the "separate input folders" idea I can see not too difficult to find a different starting point to use the downstream approach. Thank you for the help!